# Remove selected row highlight in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to remove the selected row `hightlight`( the yellow color) from the grid and the selcted cell to be highlighted. It just needs to be plain. Since i'm working on the functionality of `cell highlight` i dont want to highlight the row.

I tried using the below `event`,

```
beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
    return false;
},
```

But my `event`

```
  onCellSelect: function (rowid,iCol,cellcontent,e) {

                },
```

is not getting fired.

When i tried using the below `css`,

```
.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight
{
    border: 1px solid red !important; // Desirable border color
    background: none !important; // Desirable background color
    color: black !important; // Desirable text color
}
```

the selected row has borders showing red color on each cell and a light gray row highlight which doesn't look good.

I need a simple proper wa to get rid of the row highlight and to highlight the selected cell.

Comment: use dev tools and see which class names are overriding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/yNw3C/9234/

Adding

```
.ui-state-highlight{
     border:none!important;
    background:none!important;
}
```

Removes the default highlight.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `return false` in the `beforeSelectRow` is correct way to prevent selection of the rows. If you use currently `onCellSelect` you can just move the code of `onCellSelect` in `beforeSelectRow` or to call `onCellSelect` from `beforeSelectRow`. You need just `$.jgrid.getCellIndex` or `cellIndex` property of  to get the index of the cell in the row. The code could be like below:

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $td = $(e.target).closest("td"),
        iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]),
        onCellSelect = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "onCellSelect");

    if ($.isFunction(onCellSelect)) {
        onCellSelect.call(this, rowid, iCol, $td.html(), e);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar solution, but I just programmatically removed the highlight class after it would be loaded. Depending on which configurations you have, different events may be fired when you click on a cell, so you may need to add this function to multiple events (`onSelectCell`, `beforeEditCell`, `onSelectRow`). This will remove any rows that are highlighted, as well as the hoverrow effect that I got despite setting `hoverrows:false`.

```
function(rowId) {
   var row=$('#'+rowId);
   row.removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
   row.removeClass('ui-state-hover);
   row.find('.ui-state-highlight').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
   row.find('.ui-state-hover).removeClass('ui-state-hover);
}
```